# Bigquery run one query using multiple datasets- Query error: Too many arguments to FORMAT for pattern

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use loop function to save some efforts running same query using 2 datasets in Bigquery. I created a table which has below metrics (this was created successfully, I saw it under projects):

```
DECLARE data_set_list ARRAY<STRING>

DEFAULT ['12345678', '45678912'];

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `xxx.TEST.Test_file`  
(date DATE, data_source STRING,promo_identifier STRING,promo_description STRING,deviceCategory STRING, channelGrouping STRING, sourcemedium STRING,landing_page STRING,site STRING, region STRING,
sessions INT64, total_events INT64, orders INT64, duration INT64, revenue FLOAT64);
```

Then I had below query to insert numbers however getting error message:"Query error: Query error: Query error: Too many arguments to FORMAT for pattern "\n\nINSERT INTO `xx.Test_file` \n\nSELECT date,data_source,\npromo_identifier, promo_description, deviceCategory, channelGrouping, sourcemedium, landing_page,\nsite, region,\nSUM(sessions) AS Sessions, SUM(total_events) AS Total_events, SUM(orders) AS Orders, SUM(duration) AS Duration, SUM(revenue) AS Revenue\nfrom \n\n\n\n(select * from `xx.xxx.masterdata` )\ngroup by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\n\n\n"; Expected 1; Got 2 at [15:1]

```
 FOR data_set IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(data_set_list) as id) DO

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

 FORMAT(

  """

 INSERT INTO `xxx.TEST.Test_file` 

SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", Date) as date,data_source,
promo_identifier, promo_description, deviceCategory, channelGrouping, sourcemedium, landing_page,
site, region,
SUM(sessions) AS Sessions, SUM(total_events) AS Total_events, SUM(orders) AS Orders, SUM(duration) AS Duration, SUM(revenue) AS Revenue
from 

(select * from `xxx.xxx.masterdata` )
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

 """

 , data_set.id);

 END FOR;
```

I found out that when I bring in , data_set.id, it returns error saying "Expected 1; Got 2". when I bring in , data_set.id, data_set.id it returns error saying " Expected 1; Got 3". As this is my first time learning loop, can anyone tell me what does the data_set.id do here?

Comment: You should escape `%` in `FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", Date)` first. Use `FORMAT_DATE("%%Y/%%m/%%d", Date)` instead.  And where do you want to put `data_set.id` ?  Put `%s` where you want to replace it with `data_set.id`.

Comment: Hi@Jaytiger, thanks for your reply. Can you share what trick "%s"does here? I tried to replace it with data_set.id but got error: "Syntax error: Illegal input character "%" at [37:3]"

Comment: I hope more information about date will help, actually there is a "date" column from `xxx.xxx.masterdata`, format DATE, eg: 2021-12-08. Much appreciated your help@Jaytiger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string

Assuming that in `xxx.yyy.masterdata`, `xxx` is your fixed project name and `yyy` is what you want to replace with `id` from `data_set_list`.

Below query will show you how a query is being generated.

```sql
DECLARE data_set_list ARRAY<STRING> DEFAULT ['12345678', '45678912'];

FOR data_set IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(data_set_list) as id) DO
-- later change below line with `EXECUTE IMMEIDATE` for actual run.
SELECT -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
FORMAT("""
  INSERT INTO `xxx.TEST.Test_file` 
  SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%%Y/%%m/%%d", Date) as date,data_source,
         promo_identifier, promo_description, deviceCategory, channelGrouping, sourcemedium, landing_page,
         site, region,
         SUM(sessions) AS Sessions, SUM(total_events) AS Total_events, SUM(orders) AS Orders, SUM(duration) AS Duration, SUM(revenue) AS Revenue
    FROM (select * from `xxx.%s.masterdata` )
   GROUP BY  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;
""", data_set.id);
END FOR;
```

one of formatted query string:
[image]